# Wikidata SPARQL Query Filter Or

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to query Wikidata for all items that are an instance of [`business`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4830453) OR [`nonprofit organization`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q163740).

The following works for one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?organization WHERE {
  ?organization wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453
}
```

But that doesn't retrieve all of them. Just all the businesses.

I have tried the following as well, but none seem to work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?organization WHERE {
  ?organization wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453 || wd:Q163740
}
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?organization WHERE {
  ?organization wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453, wd:Q163740
}
```

Of course I could just make two separate requests and combine them after the fact, but that doesn't seem as efficient and seems like there should be a better way to handle this.

Comment: See also the [`UNION`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#alternatives) keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution :

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
    VALUES ?o { wd:Q4830453 wd:Q163740 } 
    ?s wdt:P31 ?o.
}
```

Be aware that the following query might also be a solution. However, `FILTER` a solution is never an efficient way to achieve something if another possibility exist.

```
SELECT * 
WHERE { 
    ?s wdt:P31 ?o.
    FILTER (?o IN (wd:Q4830453, wd:Q163740 ) )
}
```

Comment: or the pre SPARQL 1.1 era way `FILTER (?o = wd:Q4830453 || ?o = wd:Q163740 )`